# How can I use <span> with Jekyll and Github Pages?

Tags: html, css, github, markdown, jekyll

My friend made a website with Google sites, and I showed him Jekyll and Markdown which he decided he liked a lot better, so I'm porting his website to a Github Pages site.

On one page he had these three columns which I wanted to recreate in Markdown.
[Page I'm trying to recreate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDJdC.png)

I saw [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50974387/11518069) which said that I could get Markdown inside of a div if I instead used a <span> with `display:block;` style.

I tried this setup:

```
<span style="display:block; float:left;">**Left Column Title

Thing 1

Thing 2

Thing 3

</span>

<span style="display:block; float:right;">**Right column title**

Thing 4

Thing 5

Thing 6

</span>
```

But instead of the expected result of

```
Left Column Title     Right Column Title

Thing 1               Thing 4

Thing 2               Thing 5

Thing 3               Thing 6
```

I get [this. The formatting does not work at all.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j4zp.png) The weirdest part is that you can see the closing </span> but not the opening <span>

Comment: Don't use `span`, use `div`; `div` are `display: block` per default, `span` are `display: inline`  per default. Don't make things more complex for yourself for no reason.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I was using `span` because you can have markdown in it. Anyways, turns out you can use markdown in a div (at least with kramdown) if you use `<div markdown="1"`. Thanks for the super helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pure HTML snippet that would work:

```html
<div style="witdh: 100%;">
  <div style="float:left; width: 50%;">
    <h2>Left column title</h2>
    <p>Thing 1</p>
    <p>Thing 2</p>
    <p>Thing 3</p>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; width: 50%;">
    <h2>Right column title</h2>
    <p>Thing 4</p>
    <p>Thing 5</p>
    <p>Thing 6</p>
  </div>
<div>
```

So for your markdown, you could go with:

```
<div style="witdh: 100%;">
  <div style="float:left; width: 50%;">
    **Left column title**
    
    Thing 1

    Thing 2

    Thing 3
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; width: 50%;">
    **Right column title**
    
    Thing 4

    Thing 5

    Thing 6
  </div>
<div>
```

A set of general advise though:

1. Learn a little bit about the different HTML elements and their default `display`, that would help you choose the right element for the right job:

   > #### Block-level Elements
   >
   > A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).
   >
   > Examples of block-level elements:
   >
   > - `<div>`
   > - `<h1>` - `<h6>`
   > - `<p>`
   > - `<form>`
   > - `<header>`
   > - `<footer>`
   > - `<section>`
   >
   > ---
   >
   > #### Inline Elements
   >
   > An inline element does not start on a new line and only takes up as much width as necessary.
   > Examples of inline elements:
   >
   > - `<span>`
   > - `<a>`
   > - `<img>`

   <sup>*Source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp*</sup>
2. Learn about floating, because floating is relative to the parent container, and you seem to have missed that important fact:

   > The `float` property is used for positioning and formatting content e.g. let an image float left to the text in a container.
   >
   > The `float` property can have one of the following values:
   >
   > - left - The element floats to the left of its container
   > - right - The element floats to the right of its container
   > - none - The element does not float (will be displayed just where it occurs in the text). This is default
   > - inherit - The element inherits the float value of its parent

   <sup>*Source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp*</sup>