# GitHub Markdown Links In List Do Not Display Correctly

Tags: github, markdown

**Issue**

I noticed on GitHub that links do not display correctly when they are inserted into a list as seen below.

I created a [bug](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/1387) for this also on GitHub a week ago but have not heard back yet.

**Working image using markdown**

```
**Here is a link:**
[Link](https://github.com/)
```

**Image in a list**

```
**Here is a link in a list:**
<ol>
  <li>Text [Link](https://github.com/) text</li>
  <li>Text</li>
</ol>
```

**Screenshot of the issue**

[image]

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368902/how-can-i-wrap-my-markdown-in-an-html-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason for not using only markdown, because this works

```
**Here is a link in a list:**

1. Text [Link](https://github.com/) text
2. Text
```

I think you cannot mix markdown inside html

Comment: But how about an unordered list? `- ![](link)` this doesn't work but using only markdown