# Show README.md file contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, readme

I am downloading README.md file contents using `axios` in react. The contents are loaded in `base64`. I want to show all of the contents inside this readme file. I followed [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928530/how-do-i-load-a-markdown-file-into-a-react-component) but none of them worked for me. Below is my code.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function App() {
  const [md, setMd] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchReadMeContents() {
            const response = await axios({
                url: "https://api.github.com/repos/zafar-saleem/anymnd/git/blobs/7af90ceab018a889b46634331cab822d94ff2b19",
            });
            console.log('response: ', response.data);
            const text = await response.data.content;
            setMd(text);
        }
        fetchReadMeContents();
    }, []);
  return (
    <code className="App">
      {md}
    </code>
  );
}
```

The above code renders below.

```
IyMgUmVxdWlyZW1lbnRzCkJlbG93IGlzIHRoZSBnZXR0aW5nIHN0YXJ0ZWQg c2VjdGlvbiB0byBzdGFydCB0aGUgcHJvamVjdC4gRm9yIG1vcmUgZGV0YWls cywgcGxlYXNlIHJlYWQgdGhlIFt3aWtpXShodHRwczovL2dpdGh1Yi5jb20v emFmYXItc2FsZWVtL2JyZWxhLXRlc3Qvd2lraSkgcGFnZS4KCiMjIEdldHRp bmcgc3RhcnRlZApJbiBvcmRlciB0byBydW4gdGhpcyBwcm9qZWN0IGluIHRo ZSBicm93c2VyIHN1Y2Nlc3NmdWxseSwgcGxlYXNlIGZvbGxvdyB0aGUgc3Rl cHMgYmVsb3chCgogICAgMS4gQ2xvbmUgdGhpcyByZXBvc2l0b3J5LgogICAg Mi4gY2QgaW50byBgL3Jvb3RgIGkuZS4gYGJyZWxhLXRlc3QvYCBkaXJlY3Rv cnkuCiAgICAzLiBSdW4gYHlhcm4vbnBtIGluc3RhbGxgIGNvbW1hbmQgdG8g ZG93bmxvYWQgYW5kIGluc3RhbGwgYWxsIGRlcGVuZGVuY2llcy4KICAgIDQu IFRvIHJ1biB0aGlzIHByb2plY3QgdXNlIGBucG0gc3RhcnQveWFybmAgY29t bWFuZCBpbiBjb21tYW5kIGxpbmUuCiAgICA
```

Here is codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-wave-8rf4l?file=/src/App.js:0-590.

How can I render readme file contents?

Comment: Why is your markdown in base64? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of having it as markdown.

Comment: @Andy Maybe that is a question need to be asked from github team.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `atob()` and `btoa()` built-in functions to convert base64 and strings together.

**1. Convert String to Base64** ([MDN describes btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa))

> The `btoa()` method creates a Base64-encoded ASCII string from a binary string (i.e., a String object in which each character in the string is treated as a byte of binary data).

```
const encodedData = btoa('Hello, world'); // encode a string
```

**2. Convert Base64 to String** ([MDN describes atob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob))

> The `atob()` function decodes a string of data that has been encoded using Base64 encoding.

```
const decodedData = atob(encodedData); // decode the string
```

So you can use the following code to render the contents of your README.md file.

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchReadMeContents() {
    const response: any = await axios({
      url: readmeFileUrl,
    });
    const text: any = await response.text();
    if (response.status === 200) {
      setMd(atob(text));
    }
  }
  if (readmeFileUrl) {
    fetchReadMeContents();
  }
}, [readmeFileUrl]);

return (
  <code>{md}</code>
);
```

Comment: That seems to be working but it does not format the contents as it is in readme file. Any idea about that?

Comment: Check if it can help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368902/how-can-i-wrap-my-markdown-in-an-html-div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29368902/how-can-i-wrap-my-markdown-in-an-html-div)